# Convert a 16 Bit Binary Value to Octal

Tags: binary, octal

Hello I would like to know of a quick and easy way to perform a number conversion of this binary value:

**1000100000001011**
 to octal.

In hex I can convert fairly quickly by hand to **0xAA0B**. To come up with the decimal value of this binary  takes a bit more work but eventually you can arrive at **32,768 + 2,048 + 11 = 34,827**.

I know the octal pattern works like **8 = 10, 9 = 11 .... 16 = 20, 17 = 21 ... 24 = 30,** etc. However I am having trouble converting to octal without a large amount of effort.

Could anybody clear this up for me and perhaps provide a short-hand method that can help convert binary to octal. Programming examples are nice but I'm really looking for an explanation. Thanks

Comment: Each octal digit (octit?) takes 3 bits. Break your binary number into groups of 3 bits (starting from the LSB, of course) and convert. If you use the same trick in hex, breaking into groups of 4 bits, you'll see that it's actually 0x880B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest method is to break the binary number into 3-bit chunks from the right end, pad with 0's from the left as needed, then convert each chunk to an octal digit.

For example,

```
1000100000001011 -> 001 000 100 000 001 011 [2 0's added to the left]
                 ->   1   0   4   0   1   3
                 -> 104013
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!